# Distributive property of matrix-vector multiplication?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, vectors

I know that matrix multiplication is not distributive but what about matrix-vector multiplication? If $A \in \mathbb{R^{m \times n}}$ and $\vec{x}+\delta \vec{x} \in \mathbb{R^{n \times 1}}$. Then can I write $A(\vec{x}+\delta \vec{x})$ as $A(\vec{x}) + A(\delta \vec{x})$? If yes, what is this property/law called?

Comment: Yes, it's [linearity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linearity#In_mathematics)

Comment: Matrix multiplication is not generally commutative, but it is [distributive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication#Distributivity)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Matrix-vector multiplication is a special case of matrix multiplication, which is [distributive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication#Distributivity).

(In general, matrix multiplication is not commutative, but it is distributive.)

Your claim that $A(\vec{x}+\delta \vec{x})=A(\vec{x}) + A(\delta \vec{x})$ can also be seen as [linearity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linearity#In_mathematics).